# Is it correct to use having been. For ex. The map having been done at home is beautiful

Tags: past-perfect

Where can we use phrase such as "...having been" I want to make sentences with "being" and "having been"

> The map having been done at home is beautiful.

Comment: Exactly what does your exercise ask you to do? Do the instructions say only _Form sentences using "being" and "having been"_? Are there any other instructions?

Answer (score 0):

> The map, having been made at home, was beautiful.
>
> The map was beautiful, having been made at home.

Both correct, but note Edwin Ashworth's comment : the sentence implies that home-made products are usually beautiful. Although this might often be true of baking, one would usually expect a home-made map to be less appealing.

Note commas to separate a subordinate clause. "Done" is acceptable but "made" is much better.

> Being and having been a lover of art for many years, I thoroughly enjoyed the visit to the gallery.
>
> He disliked dogs intensely, being and having been since youth of the opinion that they are unclean and unpredictable creatures.

"Being and having been" emphasizes not only current but long-standing possession of some trait, skill or view. Note that it usually requires qualification.

Comment: Using ', having been made at home,' rather than ', which had been made at home,' requires some degree of consequentiality. Which isn't present here without prior context.